# Swift: Converting NSNumber into NSString (NSNumber is not a subtype of NSString)

Tags: core-data, swift

In my app, I'm going into CoreData and grabbing an entry whose type is a `Double`, then I'm trying to put that value into a text field in my app.

This looks like

`lengthTextField.text = lastSession.length` but I'm getting the error `NSNumber is not a subtype of NSString`

The value of `lastSession.length` is 6.0 for reference. Any suggestions on how to properly put that data in my text field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In core data numbers are backed by `NSNumber`. You can view the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html)

In swift you can access the string representation of the number through the instance property `stringValue`

```
lengthTextField.text = lastSession.length.stringValue
```

Comment: backed "by default". You can choose to use scalars.

Comment: @Aurelius Thanks! I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to format the NSNumber's doubleValue member to a string before outputting.

```
let x:NSNumber = 6.0
let s:String = String(format:"%f", x.doubleValue) //formats the string to accept double/float
println(s)
```